# Is it possible to add vector tile layer published by GeoServer layer using ArcGIS JS API？

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, vector-tiles

GeoServer can publish vector tile layer in format of “application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector”, and I believe the ArcGIS JavaScript API supports this format. So is it possible to add vector tile layer published by GeoServer layer using ArcGIS JSAPI?Or can the ArcGIS JS API only add vector tile layer published by ArcGIS Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use other sources for vector tiles. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itrew/0b8ugjzr/1/) has an example using tiles served by [tegola](https://tegola.io/). You just need to be more explicit with the sources of your vector tiles in your `style.json` like so:

`"sources": {
  "osm": {
    "tiles": [
      "https://osm-lambda.tegola.io/v1/maps/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
    ],
    "type": "vector"
  }
},`

There is one caveat, however. While the [mapbox tile spec](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/) allows for vector tiles from multiple sources to be used in the same layer (e.g. tiles from Mapbox AND ESRI in the same layer), the ESRI JS has some quirks in it that do not allow that to work. I've written up info on tha bug [here](https://gist.github.com/itrew/ec6466736c4d7a4c41b41ea9c75e19cf).

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference - here is an example of rendering a vector layer served by `pg_tileserv`:

```js
...imports etc
const ESRI_BASEMAP = 'arcgis-terrain'
const ESRIAPI_KEY = ...

esriConfig.apiKey = ESRI_API_KEY

const vLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
  style: {
    id: 'somesource',
    version: 8,
    a: {
      models: {
        type: 'vector',
        tiles: ['http://localhost:7800/public.sometable/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'],
      },
    },
    layers: [
      {
        id: 'test',
        type: 'fill',
        source: 'a',
        minzoom: 0,
        maxzoom: 24,
        'source-layer': 'public.sometable',
        paint: {
          'fill-color': 'red,
          'fill-opacity': 0.2,
          'fill-outline-color': 'blue,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
})

const map = new Map({
  basemap: ESRI_BASEMAP,
  layers: [vLayer],
})

const view = new SceneView({
  map,
  center: [25, -31],
  zoom: 6,
  container: ref.current, // this is React.js
})
```