# How to add GeoServer vector tiles in ArcGIS using ArcGIS JS API

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, vector-tiles

I am trying to display vector tile layers from GeoServer in ArcGIS using JavaScript API. I have referred [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300398/is-it-possible-to-add-vector-tile-layer-published-by-geoserver-layer-using-arcgi).here they have used tegola service but i want to add "application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector" which is published in GeoServer.

In OpenLayers I am able to display using Mapbox vector tiles service is "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Cadastral:CADASTRAL@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"

Same thing I want to add in ArcGIS. How to add it in ArcGIS using JavaScript API?

Comment: I am facing the same problem currently. I tried to use ```wmts``` url which is not working as ESRI will not replace x/y/z accordingly. Using ```tms``` is not working either as the y paramater is not set correct. I also tried using EPSG:3857 / EPSG:900913 and also defining the AGOL:3857 Gridset. Nothing works. It looks like ESRI is ignoring the ```"scheme": "tms"``` option in the source. Did anyone manage to display Geoserver Vector Sources in ESRI JS 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is using a GridSet in `Google Mercator` that has `512x512` tiles like `EPSG:900913x2` and flipping the Y axis using [flipY=true](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/tms.html). I am not sure if it really always needs to be `512x512` tiles in size, but ESRI at least requires it for [Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/analyzer-error-messages/00252-tiling-scheme-is-not-supported-for-vector-tile-layers.htm) and it's also working in JS.

My final settings look like:

```js
const vecSettings = {
    style: {
      "version": 8,
      "sources": {
        "sample": {
          "type": "vector",
          "scheme": "tms",
          "tiles": [
            `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sample/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/sample:sample@EPSG:900913x2@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?token=${jwt}&flipY=true`
          ],
          "minZoom": 0,
          "maxZoom": 19
        }
      },
      "layers": [
        {
          id: 'sample',
          type: "circle",
          source: "sample",
          "source-layer": "sample",
          layout: {},
          paint: {
            "circle-color": "#31d8f9",
            "circle-stroke-color": "#000000",
            "circle-stroke-width": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
};
const layer = new VectorTileLayer(vecSettings);
```

If you are using the `AuthKey` plugin the token paramater can also be set in the `tiles URL`. Also the `Geofence` plugin is working in combination with GWC and Vector Tiles and all rules are applied accordingly.

Comment: can you access the attributes? like the different columns etc